# Solve $ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{n^{\log \left( \log n \right)}}{n^{\log n}} $

Tags: calculus

I did it as follows,

$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{n^{\log \left( \log n \right)}}{n^{\log n}}
$$
$$
=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}n^{\log \left( \log n \right)}\times n^{-\log n}
$$
$$
=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}n^{\log \left( \log n \right) -\log n}=-\infty 
$$

**Question**: What do you think please? I see that it should go to 0, which means $n^{\log{n}}$ grows faster, so we can say that $n^{\log{\log{n}}} = o(n^{\log{n}})$, where $o(\cdot)$ is little-oh.

Comment: It's correct except for the fact that you (probably) meant $0$ instead of $-\infty$ at the end of the last line, and you can say that $n^{\log \log n} = o\left(n^{\log n}\right)$ as well.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon. Thank you very much. I did not ralized that ${\log \left( \log n \right) -\log n}$ is the one that goes to $-\infty$, which means we will have $\frac 1n$, which means 0 please?

Comment: Yes, in fact you'll have something going to zero even faster than $\frac 1n$, but basically it's zero.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon. My concentration is at its lowest level :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with your last limit,
\begin{align*}
&\vdots  \\
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n^{\log \log n - \log n} &= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathrm{e}^{\log n(\log \log n - \log n)}  \\
    &= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\mathrm{e}^{\log n \log \frac{\log n}{n}}  \\
\end{align*}
In the indicated limit, $\log n \rightarrow \infty$ and $\log \frac{\log n}{n} \rightarrow \log 0^+ \rightarrow -\infty$, so their product $\rightarrow -\infty$, and thus the exponential of their product $\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: Thank you. So, $e^{-\infty}$ will go to zero since it's a fraction. Thanks. Lastly, please what $\to \log0^{+}$ means here?

Comment: "approaches the logarithm of something approaching zero from above".  We can't take the logarithm of something approaching zero since not all values near zero are in the domain of the logarithm, however for large $n$, $\frac{\log n}{n}$ is a ratio of positive numbers, so we are approaching zero only from values larger than zero.

Comment: Thanks. Oh is it because log is not defined at 0 please?

Comment: @Avra : The logarithm isn't defined for $0$ or for negative numbers, so we should never try to evaluate it there...

Comment: Thank you very much.